# Installing Nvidia , Cuda , Tensorflow in Genome ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

**MY Lap Specs** : HP - Pavilion -p027Tx notebook
             : Ubuntu Genome 16.04
              : Nvidia Geforce 830M

I am new to this ubuntu community (OS).
I want to install **Nvidia graphics drivers , Cuda ,CuDnn , Tensorflow** for Deeplearning.I am very new to all commands in Linux.

Can anyone help out in this.
I followed the documentation , but could'nt help me out.
Since i am very ameture in this installations , i want someone to guide me in installations

Thank you !!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you open a terminal. The usual shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on ubuntu. If gnome doesn't have this shortcut, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and on the little window that opens write

```
gnome-terminal
```

Once inside the terminal write:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Enter your password when prompted and if asked [Y/N] type y and press enter.

After that restart your PC.
You can also restart from the terminal with the command:

```
reboot
```

That's as far as my knowledge goes.I don't know about the rest you want to install. Google them and you will probably find answers, or wait for someone to respond.